# Show element onClick in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, events, redux

I've got one question.

Do I need to call an action creator to show/hide another component basing on the search button (true - clicked / false - initial state)? My search form is not on the same level/same component as button. Using redux is the only way? I'm just curious.

Comment: Either that or lift the state up to a common component that includes both search form and the toggle element. Redux is nothing but the top level state with a bunch of callback functions.

Comment: You can do it like in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pass-function-to-component) - it's like norbertpy mentioned.

Comment: I did it with redux. The main problem was that my search button was a child of a header component but my searchbar was outside of it. So If i wanted pure react I would have to pass state through couple components.